# CFG to RG Conversion

Tags: regular-languages, context-free

I'm struggling with this question. I would appreciate a detailed solution as it would help me better understand the subject.

Convert the following Context Free grammar into a Regular Grammar:
S -> aSb | A
A -> bA | a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't convert context free grammar into regular grammar **in general**. Because CFG is $Type{-}2$ grammar which has less restriction than $Type{-}3$ RG grammar. CFG generate more complex languages that RG can ever do.

When CFG generates a language which is regular then you must write equivalent RG for that regular language. But your grammar generates the language $a^nb^*ab^n$, which is clearly not regular. That's why we are  not able to write equivalent regular grammar for that language.

Every $Type{-}3$ RG grammar also satisfies conditions of $Type{-}2$,  $Type{-}1$,  $Type{-}0$ grammar. So we can say every  $Type{-}3$ grammar is also  $Type{-}2$ grammar but the converse isn't true.

**N. B.** - Small suggestions you need to understand Chomsky Hierarchy very carefully.

Comment: I am aware of the restrictions of each grammar type (as in this diagram https://i.imgur.com/PdOsMo8.png ), but is there a particular solution for this question?
This is a question from a past final exam, so it should have a solution.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: So if I were to get a similar question, am I to separate the CFG into multiple RG to solve the question? or is there an alternate solution.

Comment: If you carefully read my answer, I mentioned that when CFG generate a language which is regular then you must write equivalent RG for that regular language. And for  one regular  language more than one RG grammar possible to write.